# App Transport Security Exceptions IOS9

Tags: ios, flickr, ios9

I am writing an IOS9 app which uses flickr.

Flicker uses an url format of
https://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/

The farm id is a number

In my info.plist I have defined whitelisted domains
NSAppTransportSecurity - NSExceptionDomains

How can I define these for the farm id as a wild card?

Currently I just did
farm1.staticflickr.com
farm2.staticflickr.com......up till 9 but I am unsure how far flickr goes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an exception for `staticflickr.com` and in that exception add a key called `NSIncludesSubdomains` and set it to true.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>      
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>staticflickr.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>         
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't realise realise farm1.staticflickr.com counted as a sub-domain