# Strange behavior with WKWebView's loadHTMLString method. Images are not loading sometimes

Tags: html, image, cocoa, wkwebview

I am working on a mac app project.Using WKWebView's loadHTMLString method,I am able to construct a web page view,it works well except for the image loading part.

For example:

```
NSString *string1 = @"<img src=\"https://apppie.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/photo-sep-14-7-40-59-pm_small1.jpg\">"
[pWebView loadHTMLString: string1 baseURL: nil];
```

That works well. But once I change `https:` to `http:`,the web page is broken, image is not showing anymore. I have checked both urls on Firefox browser,they all go well. I don't understand why this is happening.

And then I try to replace all `http:` with `https:`,most of images of the web page load properly, but still not all of them.(Again,I double check it in Firefox,all images show up without problem),so I am pretty sure there is something wrong with WKWebView configuration,how can I fix that?Thanks a lot.

My OSX version: 10.11 public beta 5; xCode version: 7.0 beta.

Comment: If you are developing for iOS9, you must read about `NSAppTransportSecurity `. Here is an SO question / answer to get you started.  `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382541/app-tranport-security-exeptions-ios9`

Comment: @DavidDelMonte You've saved my day! Your answer point me to the right solution and completely solve my problem. Great answer, thanks a lot. Would you repost this as a formal answer? So I can mark your answer as final solution. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are developing for iOS9, you must read about NSAppTransportSecurity. [Here is an SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382541/app-tranport-security-exeptions-ios%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B9) / answer to get you started.

My own info.plist file includes:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

This is probably much more open than I should be, but I'll change over time to limit access to specific URLs that I need. How to do this is also shown in the linked q/a.

Glad this helped!